# Object does not support indexing when using random choice()

Tags: python, random

```
    import collections
    from random import choice

    card = collections.namedtuple('card', ['rank', 'suit'])

    class FrenchDeck:
      ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
      suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

      def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
                                        for rank in self.ranks]

      def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

        def __getitem__(self, position):
          return self._cards[position]



    deck = FrenchDeck()

    choice(deck)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cards.py", line 24, in <module>
        choice(deck)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\random.py", line 258, in choice
        return seq[i]
    TypeError: 'FrenchDeck' object does not support indexing
```

This is from Fluent Python, and I have typed it in as it is in the book.  I am wondering if this is an issue that relates to newer Python distributions.

Comment: I haven't heard of Fluent Python, but I will say that the only programming tutorial I've found that's any good (for any language) is the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem: method `__getitem__` is declared within method `__len__`. That's why indexing is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

I am also not familiar with Fluent Python but you may want to try using both python 3.3 and 2.7 whichever you didn't use here, they have very different syntax

Comment: This is not his problem. As pointed out by @DYZ, his indention was off, not his version.